# Gnu Radio symbol recovery

Tags: gnuradio, fsk

I have successfully built [Simulation example: FSK](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Simulation_example:_FSK). Everything works fine and I'm getting same results as in example.

For the next step I would like to save demodulated binary data in file but I'm getting way too many samples per bit (maybe because of repeat block used in beginning of simulation?). How do I decimate such a large amount of samples? When using rational resampler (between Frequency Xlating FIR Filter and Quadrature demod) with decimation 1056 I get

> sched: <block rational_resampler_base<IN_T,OUT_T,TAP_T> (1)> is requesting more input data
> than we can provide.
> ninput_items_required = 36778
> max_possible_items_available = 8191
> If this is a filter, consider reducing the number of taps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. I will share my solution. After some googling I realized that this is clock recovery problem, so I used Clock Recovery MM block (with default parameters except for Omega). From [Clock Recovery MM](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Clock_Recovery_MM)

> If the input signal pulses do not have peaks (e.g. rectangular pulses) the input signal should be conditioned with a matched pulse filter or other appropriate filter to peak the input pulses. For a rectangular base pulse that is N samples wide, the matched filter taps would be [1.0/float(N)]*N

As rectangular pulses is my case I added Decimating fir filter with taps **np.ones(int(samp_rate/baud)-1)/int(samp_rate/baud)**
and decimation 1056/4 = 264 and for Clock Recovery MM (which is decimation block) I put Omega = 4.
[image]